# How to join the CMIS, using the EJB?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cmis

The problem, you need to write a type manager using CMIS. We have the following architecture:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAFv4.gif

For the connection enough to get the session.

```
private Session getSession() {
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = SessionFactoryImpl.newInstance();
    Map<String, String> parameter = new HashMap<String, String>();
    parameter.put(SessionParameter.USER, "");
    parameter.put(SessionParameter.PASSWORD, "");
    parameter.put(SessionParameter.ATOMPUB_URL, this.atomUrl);
    parameter.put(SessionParameter.BINDING_TYPE, BindingType.ATOMPUB.value());
    parameter.put(SessionParameter.REPOSITORY_ID, getIDKey());
    Repository repository = sessionFactory.getRepositories(parameter).get(0);
    return sessionFactory.createSession(parameter);
}
```

And then you can, for example, get a list of all folders:

```
public List<String> getAllFolder() {
    List<String> folders = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (session != null) {
         Folder root = session.getRootFolder();
         ItemIterable<CmisObject> children = root.getChildren();
         for (CmisObject child : children) {
            folders.add(child.getName());
         }
     }
     return folders;
}
```

Where to make connections with CMIS? It would be desirable to have access to the session of any Session Bean, as in the case Persistence Context.

Answer (score 1):

It depends - on security, state and lifecycle.

The CMIS session is a stateful thingy. It is aware of security (credentials) and I guess most implementaions (at least chemistry) usually cache. If you have to propagate security to cmis (on whose behalf you are calling), you can create and bind one CMIS session to one stateful session bean. It may be possible to get in injected somehow, but I guess ejbCreate (of whatever its called nowadays) can do.

If security (propagation) does not matter and it is ok for your app if all CMIS requests execute on behalf of one user (say admin) I would build a cmis session pool dealing with the creation of the session and make your ejb ask that pool for an instance. Alfresco WCM Quickstart has a sample implementation.

Either way: Be clear that in contrast to JPA, CMIS will NOT participate in (container managed) transactions at all. So depending on what is going on in your session beans, it may not make sense to make use of EJB at all.

Comment: Do you offer a one stateful session bean? In the method create a connection:
@ PostConstruct
   private void init () {
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = SessionFactoryImpl.newInstance();
    ...
    session = sessionFactory.createSession(parameter);
   }


I understand you correctly?

Comment: It depends on your app. Be clear that security (on which users behalf you are executing) and transactions are the main features session beans provide. Security and transactional context does not propagate to CMIS. It may be difficult (security) or even impossible (transactions) to get it "right". A CMIS session may seem like just another (jdbc) session but you may need to treat it very differently - it depends on your app.